# Is it possible to to send bulk pre-rendered email via the SendGrid API?

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I checked the SendGrid API docs, and didn't find a possibility to send bulk pre-rendered emails. Is this possible?

What I want to do is use my own templating engine to render the individual email content, and then upload these (including recipient, subject and the mail body) as bulk to the SendGrid systems.

I can send transactional mails without a problem, but it's currently too slow for large amounts of mails.

I'm currently using the Node.js library https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs

Comment: How many recipients are you sending per request? You can send up to 10k recipients per request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several possibilities. Generally to send a bunch of email quickly, I'd recommend the [SMTPAPI](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/index.html) which allows you to send up to 10,000 emails from one request. However, this requires using SendGrid's [substitution system](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/substitution_tags.html) to customize the messages. *Since you want to use your own templating system, this probably isn't the best option for you.*

One thing I'd look toward is simply code optimizations, as in parallel sending a bunch of email probably shouldn't take too terribly long. Some of our biggest senders have been known to dump millions of emails at once through individual connections. *Although, long term this may not be the best solution.*

---

If neither of those answers work there is a way to send a bunch of email to SendGrid through one connection: SMTP. However, this will require removing the [SendGrid Node Library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs) and replacing it with [NodeMailer](http://www.nodemailer.com/) (or some other SMTP library).

NodeMailer by default will keep connections open and alive so you can send multiple emails in one transaction. To do so, you'd do something like this:

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

// Create reusable transport method (opens pool of SMTP connections)
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    service: "SendGrid",
    auth: {
        user: "your_username",
        pass: "your_password"
    }
});

// Let get the users you want to send email to
var users = getAllUsersAsArray();

// Loop through your users
users.forEach(function (user){

    // Setup the message
    var mailOptions = {
        from: "You <you@example.com>",
        to: user.email,
        subject: subjectTemplate.render(user),
        text: textTemplate.render(user),
        html: htmlTemplate.render(user)
    }

    // Send mail
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
        }
    });

});
```

If you still need to take advantage of parts of SendGrid's [SMTPAPI](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/index.html), you may do so by using the [SMTPAPI Node.js library](https://github.com/sendgrid/smtpapi-nodejs) and inserting its results into the header of your message.

```
var mailOptions = {
    from: "You <you@example.com>",
    to: user.email,
    // Assuming you've created an smtpapi header instance named header
    headers: header.jsonString(),
    subject: subjectTemplate.render(user),
    text: textTemplate.render(user),
    html: htmlTemplate.render(user)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I think SendGrid is a great service, and has a good documentation. Why I want to render the mails myself is because I need to add some special links (generated by custom functions) to them. I didn't find some info about something like "custom funtions" in the docs. Is there any possibility to use such functions?

Comment: If you want to add custom links to the messages, it's probably best to generate the custom link on your end and then send it to us via the SMTPAPI and substitution tags. A number of customers end up doing this as a way to send lots of semi-custom messages. **We do not at present have any way to execute custom code (functions) on our servers.**