# Running bulk email with nodemailer in Meteor.js application

Tags: node.js, email, meteor, nodemailer

I am trying to use nodemailer in an application. After following an SO thread here [Is it possible to to send bulk pre-rendered email via the SendGrid API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695750/is-it-possible-to-to-send-bulk-pre-rendered-email-via-the-sendgrid-api), I kept on getting the below error which suggested it is a version problem. As stated on the nodemailer page that version 6- upward is required, and presently I'm running on version 7.4.0, and still getting the error.

This is my implementation:

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        MassMail: function () {
            var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
                service: "Gmail",
                auth: {
                    user: "mygmailaccount@gmail.com",
                    pass: "mygmailpassword"
                }
            });

            var collections = CollectionName.find({userId: this.userId});
           // var users = getAllUsersAsArray();

            // Loop through your users
            collections.forEach(function (collection){

                // Setup the message
                var mailOptions = {
                    from: "no-reply@christdoes.com",
                    to: students.useremail,
                    subject: subjectTemplate.render(collection),
                    text: textTemplate.render(collection),
                    html: htmlTemplate.render(collection)
                }

                // Send mail
                smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
                    if(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    }else{
                        console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
                    }
                });

            });
        }
    });
}
```

This is the error on console

```
W20170818-10:42:01.023(1)? (STDERR) C:\Programs\contract\schoolapps\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\mailer\index.js:31
W20170818-10:42:01.024(1)? (STDERR)             compile: [(...args) => this._convertDataImages(...args)],
W20170818-10:42:01.025(1)? (STDERR)                        ^^^
W20170818-10:42:01.034(1)? (STDERR)
W20170818-10:42:01.040(1)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
W20170818-10:42:01.041(1)? (STDERR)     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
W20170818-10:42:01.043(1)? (STDERR)     at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
W20170818-10:42:01.044(1)? (STDERR)     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
W20170818-10:42:01.046(1)? (STDERR)     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
W20170818-10:42:01.047(1)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
W20170818-10:42:01.049(1)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
W20170818-10:42:01.051(1)? (STDERR)     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
W20170818-10:42:01.053(1)? (STDERR)     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Programs\contract\schoolapps\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\nodemailer.js:3:16)
W20170818-10:42:01.059(1)? (STDERR)     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
W20170818-10:42:01.061(1)? (STDERR)     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10
```

Comment: Show your `package.json` and result of commands `meteor node --version` and `meteor npm --version`

Comment: You're good man, @Styx. Meteor node version is v4.8.4. How do I update without breaking anything?

Comment: Added as answer

Answer (score 1):

You can't update the `node` used in `meteor`, so solution will be to install `babel` transpiler:

```
meteor npm install --save babel-runtime
```

Comment: After installing babel how does it affect the app? Sorry, just a novice question.

Comment: I have executed as you suggested so I assume babel is installed but when i ran the app it still thre the error, what's the next thing to do? Sorry, just a novice question

Comment: How do you start your app?

Comment: And you ran this command from the answer in the your meteor project directory, right?

Comment: yes, I navigated to the meteor project directory on the cmd and ran ```meteor```.

Comment: I meant "from my answer", that one: `meteor npm install --save babel-runtime `

Comment: Yes. I did. This is the project.json in the meteor project ```{
  "name": "schoolapps",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.5.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "mailer": "^0.6.7",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.4",
    "nodemailer": "^4.0.1",
    "shared": "^0.2.0",
    "warp.email-processor": "^0.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bulk-email-verifier": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```